# Vue 3 + ESLint warning [intlify] Detected HTML

Tags: vue.js, eslint, vuejs3, vue-i18n

Getting a warning inside the console "[intlify] Detected HTML in .....", but can't figure out how to disable this warning for this specific line. I've also tried to change the eslintrc.js file to disable all v-html warnings but didn't work out.

dependencies

```
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.0-beta.15",
```

devDependencies

```
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.14",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.5.14",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.14",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.19.1",
```

Eslint config file

```
  extends: [
    'standard',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/standard'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint',
    impliedStrict: true
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-new': 'off',
    'no-var': 'off',
    indent: ['error', 2],
    semi: 0
  },
```

Answer (score 18):

### Update 2022:

With Vue-I18n Version 9+, there are two different settings depending on the used mode:

- Setting for the **composition API mode**:

  ```
  warnHtmlMessage: false
  ```
- Setting for the **legacy API mode**:

  ```
  warnHtmlInMessage: "off"
  ```

---

Citation from the [Vue-I18n V9 Release Notes](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/migration/breaking.html)

> In Vue I18n v8.x, the value of warnHtmlInMessage was "off". Therefore, by default, no warning is output to the console even if the message contains HTML.
>
> In Vue I18n v9 or later, change the default values as follows:
>
> - Legacy API mode: warnHtmlInMessage property: "warn"
> - Composition API mode: warnHtmlMessage boolean property, default true

Comment: Damn this is it. I only noticed the subtle difference between these two string thanks to your answer. Cheers !

Answer (score 9):

This comes from **warnHtmlInMessage** [vue i18n](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/migration/breaking.html#change-warnhtmlinmessage-option-default-value) , what you need to change is the options of it when you create it.

Probably you will have a **createI18n** or a **VueI18n** method somewhere.
In there you can disable it like:

```
createI18n({
    warnHtmlInMessage: 'off' // disable of the Detected HTML in message
});
```

Comment: If this does not work for you, you probably have a never version of Vue18n. See answer from Boy.Lee, property name and value have changed.

Answer (score 7):

for vue i18N v9.x or later version, you can use "warnHtmlMessage" option in the demo code.

```
const i18n = setupI18n({
  globalInjection: true,
  legacy: false,
  warnHtmlMessage: false, // disable warning HTML in message
  locale: 'en',
  fallbackLocale: 'en',
  messages: {
    en
  }
})
```